# iOS 13 UITableViewCell custom accessoryView goes out of bounds

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios13, accessoryview

Working with the latest iOS 13 beta

I really don't understand if it's beta issues or my issue,
but I don't have this problem with iOS 12

code

```
 let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
 button.setTitle("connect", for: .normal)
 button.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xFF0E83)
 button.sizeToFit()
 cell.accessoryView = button
 cell.textLabel?.text = "Title"
 cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Subtitle"
```

with result

[image]

Did someone had the same issue and found a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved in the latest beta of iOS 13.1 (beta 2)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you put the uibutton in a uiview it will work on iOS 13.0.

Comment: what I mean exactly is that this seems to be associated with UIButtons with text content explicitly. I have noticed uibuttons with images only do not behave this way. If the problematic uibutton is wrapped like so: UIView(frame: button.bounds) and the resulting view is added as the accessory the correct layout behavior is the result. The view will respect the cells contentView layout margins.

Comment: Yes, it works but you have to adjust the frame of your UIView. Under iOS 13.1 this problem is solved using UIButton only.

Answer (score 1):

I am using UILabel instead of UIButton, and same issue occurred with iOS13.1.
@Amerino's workaround does well.

Comment: My issue is solved using only UIButton under iOS 13.1

Comment: The problem of UILabel with wrong position in Accessoryview goes on even with iOS13.1. And works fine with iOS12 and prior. help needed THX!