# Wrong position of UIButton as accessory view of a UITableViewCell in iOS 13

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios13, accessoryview

I have a cell where I assign an UIButton as the accessory view like this:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 31))
button.setTitle("My button", for: .normal)
cell.accessoryView = button
```

The result normally looks like this:
[image]

However using Xcode 11 (Beta) and running on iOS 13 the button's position is out of bounds of the screen:
[image]

Am I adding the button incorrectly or is this some kind of a bug in SDK/iOS 13?

Comment: Use autolayout constraints rather than setting the frame

Comment: @Paulw11 How do I use autolayout constraints on a cell accessory view?

Comment: Check my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791055/ios-13-uitableviewcell-custom-accessoryview-goes-out-of-bounds) this is solved in the latest iOS 13.1 beta

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 13 UITableViewCell custom accessoryView goes out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791055/ios-13-uitableviewcell-custom-accessoryview-goes-out-of-bounds)

Comment: @MartinoBonfiglioli It was indeed solved. Can you write your comment as an answer so that I may accept it?

Comment: @pajevic I just can't :(